# Versioning Issue With Local NuGet Server Packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, jenkins, nuget

**Some background:**
At my company, I have been working the last few months with converting our C# libraries to function on .dll references instead of project to project references. To do this, we have created a local NuGet server which contains NuGet packages for all of our libraries projects. We have Jenkins jobs set up for every project which build new NuGet packages and add them to the server every time a change is made to one of them.

For working on a single project, this system works great. You only have to worry about updating your packages folder through Visual Studio's NuGet manager, and then the rest is just writing code and building.

**The issue:**
When you add a new reference, or update your packages through NuGet, NuGet automatically specifies that specific version of the project that you selected in NuGet. With the current system I have setup, rebuilding a project locally will then replace it's .dll in the packages folder so that all projects that reference it can see these new changes you're testing. However, the issue come in that locally built projects have a different version than our Jenkins built packages. Our local builds use a different versioning system from our Jenkins builds so that you can easily tell whether something was built using Jenkins, or if some of the .dlls came from a developer's build. Because of this different versioning scheme, the reference of projects to the project breaks, because the new .dll that was built locally has a different version than the .dll that was retrieved from the NuGet server.

**Current Solution:**
For the moment, I have resolved this through the addition of a pre-build step. Before every project builds, the project calls one of my PowerShell scripts, which goes through and adds `<SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>` to every project reference in the project being built's .csproj file. This resolves the issue, but only in the sense of putting a bandaid on it. Instead of dealing with the consequences of the system, I wanted to prevent them ahead of time so that this isn't needed every time a project builds. I have tried researching a lot about NuGet packages specific versioning issues, but have not been able to find anything online even remotely close to what I am asking. This makes me think that I'm going about this wrong.

**The question:**
What can I do to solve this issue? Or am I doing something very wrong and dumb that could be easily avoided by using another system? Any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: IMO packages should have only one version stream. Either build everything in Jenkins or locally, but don't build packages in both places. This was a never-ending nightmare at my last place, as developers would sometimes push packages with versions that had no bearing on the versions generated by Jenkins, leading to to difficult-to-troubleshoot issues due to the wrong package being referenced. Draw a hard line in the sand on this; it will make everyone's lives easier.

Comment: For developers making changes to their projects locally, would I still use the same system of replacing the .dlls inside of the packages folder? One versioning stream would solve the versioning issue, but would leave building locally still somewhat messy

Comment: The workflow should be: 1) commit library code, 2) build, package and push from Jenkins, 3) update NuGet reference in Visual Studio, 4) build locally. Let Visual Studio manage the packages directory via the NuGet manager.